# click cell in range on sheet 1, input box popup, input value into that cell on sheet 2

Tags: excel, vba

When i click cell B1, an input box pops up, i put my value in and that value is then entered into cell B1. How do i make it so any cell within a range results in the same input box, and that value is inputted into the cell i clicked in that range, but on a different sheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim xRtn As Variant
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B1:C2")) Is Nothing Then
            xRtn = Application.Inputbox("Insert your value please")
            If xRtn <> False Then Target.Value = xRtn
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Example: Click cell B1 in sheet 1, input value 5, 5 is entered into cell B1 in sheet 2

Edit: i now have it inputting my value into sheet 2 but i have no idea how to make it input my value into only the specific cell i clicked, currently it inputs my value into all cells within the specified range in sheet 2

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim xRtn As Variant
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B1:C2")) Is Nothing Then
            xRtn = Application.Inputbox("Insert your value please")
            Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B1:C2").Value = xRtn
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Edit 2: solved it on my own having absolutely no clue what i was doing never touching code or vba before just trying random stuff

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim xRtn As Variant
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B1:C2")) Is Nothing Then
            xRtn = Application.Inputbox("Insert your value please")
            Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Target.Address).Value = xRtn

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: solved it on my own having absolutely no clue what i was doing never touching code or vba before just trying random stuff

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you solve your own problem, please put your well-formed answer with explanations as an answer. Later, you can accept your own answer. Other people who have the same question can follow your logic and learn that way. Else, your question remains unanswered, in appearance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim xRtn As Variant
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B1:C2")) Is Nothing Then
            xRtn = Application.Inputbox("Insert your value please")
            Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Target.Address).Value = xRtn

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```